# Karaf - Kafka OSGI bundle - Producer issue

Tags: osgi, bundle, apache-kafka, karaf, producer

I am trying to create a simple bundle for Kafka producer in apache Karaf version 4.0.3 .

Here is my Java code

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
//props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
//props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("partitioner.class","org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner");
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props,new StringSerializer(),new StringSerializer());
//for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test","data", outputData));

producer.close();
```

I have clearly declared the respective dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0_1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have deployed that kafka client bundle too.

but on starting the producer i see below exception on **first Attempt** .

```
Exception in thread "pool-135-thread-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:194)
    .
    .
    .
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.gilt.gfc.guava.future.FutureConverters$ScalaFutureAdapter$$anonfun$addListener$1.apply(FutureConverters.scala:72)
    at com.gilt.gfc.guava.future.FutureConverters$ScalaFutureAdapter$$anonfun$addListener$1.apply(FutureConverters.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner for configuration partitioner.class: Class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:255)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:78)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<clinit>(ProducerConfig.java:206)
    ... 12 more
```

And then consecutively this one ...

```
Exception in thread "pool-136-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:194)
.
.
.
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
at com.gilt.gfc.guava.future.FutureConverters$ScalaFutureAdapter$$anonfun$addListener$1.apply(FutureConverters.scala:72)
at com.gilt.gfc.guava.future.FutureConverters$ScalaFutureAdapter$$anonfun$addListener$1.apply(FutureConverters.scala:72)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

Has anyone encoutered similar issue with the bundle ??

Comment: The OSGi runtime does not care about your Maven dependencies. It only cares about the MANIFEST inside your bundle. If you load classes by name, like you seem to do, then you need to add build time configuration such that the relevant packages are added to the list of imported packages. Or you add a `DynamicImport-Package: *` to your MANIFEST. How exactly you do this depends on how you build your bundle. With the `maven-bundle-plugin`?

Comment: Yes, I've got the same problem. The funny thing is that if I embed the kafka jar (either the servicemix one or the original kafka one), when I instantiate a KafkaProducer I immediately get this error, even though I can reference the KafkaProducer just fine. Either something weird is messing up the error message, or some dark classloading is going on...

Answer (score 2):

I saw this same problem in 0.9.0. It turned out that a Thread context loader was set, and in that case Kafka uses that classloader to resolve. So the thread context classloader should either be:

- A classloader that can resolve all the Kafka related stuff
- `null`

Don't know if this is going to bite me, but adding:

```java
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
```

did the trick.

Comment: Your solution aligns with the workaround suggested in JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3218

Comment: When this pull request gets merged there should be another solution avaliable: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/1421

Answer (score 1):

using Kafka client version 0.8.2.2_1, solved the issue .

Answer (score 1):

Might me useful for others, work around suggested in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3218)

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class);

props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class);
```